# I want to add double quotes to a string, but it won't work. Help! (Python)

Tags: python, string, split

If there's a string like this:

```
A = "I" "have" "2" "phones."
```

Python will automatically concatenate these strings into one, like this:
A: `'Ihave2phones.'`
However, I'm currently trying to split this string into 4 parts with A as the input and '" "' as the delimiter.
`['I', 'have', '2', 'phones.']` is the result I'm looking for.
I've tried to put a quotation mark around A,
`"'" + A + "'"` 
but since Python already has A as 'Ihave2phones', it simply won't work.
Is there any solution to modify A as '"I" "have" "2" "phones."' or a different way to split it into 4 parts?
Thanks!

Comment: The assignment `A = "I" "have" "2" "phones."` is the same as `A = "Ihave2phones."`,  and there is no way to modify this once you make this assignment. The question is then why you make such assignments, rather than, say, `A = ["I", "have", "2", "phones."]`

Comment: Fix the upstream problem of defining the string as `A = "I" "have" "2" "phones."`.

Comment: Python uses `'`, `"`, `'''` and `"""` as quotes so that you can switch between them depending on the quotes in the string literal.

Comment: Modify it to something like A =  ' "I" "have" "2" "phones." ', then you can split it easily.

Comment: You will definitely have to do a better job of describing your problem.  Particularly why you can't just fix the assignment to do the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the quotes:

```
A = '"I" "have" "2" "phones."'
```

Then you could split it like:

```
print([i for i in A.split('"') if i.strip()])
```

Output:

```
['I', 'have', '2', 'phones.']
```

But actually, if you can add characters to the code, just write;

```
A = ['I', 'have', '2', 'phones.']
```

Comment: @KellyBundy - but that's not what OP is asking. This answers the question well. I don't see why we need to mention the list at all.

Comment: @tdelaney Sure, it worked well as well. It's not clear to me what the OP is asking, their question makes no sense, so I find adding my characters just as plausible as those others.

Comment: @KellyBundy - i'm not sure either, but its just a made up example. Perhaps OP has an external text file with qoutes like this and is experimenting with how to handle them. First step would be to duplicate quoted strings as python literals.

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah ok, that seems odd but possible :-)

Comment: @tdelaney Hmm... upon closer inspection, I just noticed that the OP literally already wrote `'"I" "have" "2" "phones."'` in their question. Literally. Just not styled as code. But with the single and double quotes like that. So if that's what they want, I must wonder why they're asking for it.

Comment: @KellyBundy - LOL I didn't notice that. I guess the answer for OP is to literally do what you literally did.

Comment: @tdelaney Even funnier, U12 had edited the question, styling several snippets as code. Just not that one...

Comment: @KellyBundy Oh yeah! haha

Answer (score 2):

Use `\"` to put a double quote character within a string with double quotes.

ex: `"Hello \"World\""`. This will be seen as `Hello "World"`

Answer (score 1):

> '" "' as the delimiter.

The quote marks are not part of the value of the variable. They are simply part of the syntax used to *define* the variable. Once the assignment is done, Python has no memory of them existing. It's like asking for what function you can apply to `x` to get `[1,3]` if `x` was defined as `1+3` and `[2,2]` if it was defined as `2+2`. That's just not part of the variable, so no operations can recover it. It's a programming language, not a key logger.